# python minidom create xml element with end tag

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm creating XML element via minidom:

```
    ele = doc.createElement("ele")
    main.appendChild(ele)   
    ele.attributes['name']= "bla"
```

But the elemnt looks:

```
<ele name="bla"/>
```

And what I want is:

```
<ele name="bla"></ele>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two forms are equivalent.  If you really want the closing tag, add an empty text node to the element:

```
>>> ele = doc.createElement('ele')
>>> ele.attributes['name']= "bla"
>>> ele.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(''))
>>> print ele.toxml()
<ele name="bla"></ele>
```

Comment: It works, but there is problem that prettyxml makes extra line for this TextNode. Is there any other way?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187718/empty-xml-element-handling-in-python) talks about this in more detail and suggests a solution.

Comment: @larsks, how to do the same thing if I am using xml.etree.ElementTree module?

Comment: You should probably open a new question for that.